# How to delete multiple rows with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Want to delete multiple rows with the help of `JdbcTemplate`.
In the below code `msgNos` is a String variable containing comma separated value like 26,27. After executing the statements it is only deleting one record.

```
String sqlQuery = " delete from canned_message where msg_no in (?)";
Object[] params = {msgNos};
int rows = smsdbJdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, params);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` where you can use named parameter.

Then in your query you can pass `List` as parameter value in the in clause

```
String sqlQuery = "delete from canned_message where msg_no in (:msgNos)";
List<Integer> params = <array list of number>;
Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("msgNos", params);
int rows = smsdbJdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, namedParameters);
```

Note: I've used `List<Integer>` use appropriate datatype as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , It worked with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Comment: how to tweak it to delete all rows in the table?

Comment: @Gaurav don't have the where condition